# Correct multi variable URL concatenation?

Tags: php, html, url, syntax-error

I've looked at previous SO entries on this, but I still am unable to understand the correct syntax for this snippet:

```
<span class="label label-<?php echo '<a href="steam://'.constant(SQ1_SERVER_ADDR).':'.constant(SQ1_SERVER_PORT).'/'>CONNECT</a>'; ?>"></span>
```

Because of the `class=` using a quotation mark `"` it is cancelled out by the same character just after the `href=`, which then in turn negates the rest of my code. The above code does produce a parser error as:

(T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Any help on the correct syntax would be most appreciated.

**EDIT:**

The following code worked for me:

```
<span class="label label-success"><?php echo '<a href="steam://'.SQ1_SERVER_ADDR.':'.SQ1_SERVER_PORT.'/">CONN‌​ECT</a>'; ?></span>
```

Somehow the snippet omitted probably a key part; `label-success">` and then I tidied up the `echo`.

Comment: I think you have one too many single quotes in there.. try `<span class="label label-<?php echo '<a href="steam://' . constant(SQ1_SERVER_ADDR) . ':' . constant(SQ1_SERVER_PORT) . '"/>CONNECT</a>'; ?>"></span>`

Comment: did you try after escaping `"`  as `\"` ?

Comment: @RamRaider I've tried modifying it to your suggestion but it displays as `CONNECT">` with no hyperlink available. @Rishi wouldn't an escape remove the important function of the `"` which signifies the start and end of the URL?

Comment: I'm not sure why you try to get `<span class="label label-<a href="steam://...">CONNECT</a>"></span>`